# Start Timer from an Event Handler, in Windows Service

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, timer, event-handling

I have a Windows Service built in vb.net that receives messages from MQTT server.   Messages are received and processed via a Sub which is attached to an Event Handler.   Works fine.

Also, I need to start a Timer that will send in parallel a signal to the "buzzer", which bips, stops, bips....   This sub routine works fine by itself.

In both a Windows service and and Windows Form, it doesn't work perfectly.  The Timer must be enabled by the Sub linked to the Event Handler (once the MQTT message is received and processed, start the timer).  The timer is usually set to 1000ms.   The sub routine finishes before the Timer hits the 1000ms, and the Tick Event is never Triggered.

In the Windows form, I worked around by using Me.Invoke.  The Timer's Tick event is triggered as expected.   But "me.invoke" doesn't exist in a Windows Service.   I don't know how to proceed to get the Tick event to be triggered.

In the Windows form, I was able to create a Delegate and call RefreshMqttScreen using Me.Invoke...

So the question is: How can I have the timer continue running once the MqttMessageReceived sub is finished running?

I can use C# instead if VB cannot do what I need...

Thanks

```
    AddHandler _mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceived, AddressOf MqttMessageReceived



Public Sub MqttMessageReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs)
       RefreshMQTTScreen(some parameters here)
End Sub


Private Sub RefreshMQTTScreen(....)
    indexBuzzer = 1
    TimerBuzzer.Interval = buzzer.intDuree
    TimerBuzzer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub TimerBuzzer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerBuzzer.Tick
    TimerBuzzer.Enabled = False
    indexBuzzer += 1

    If collBuzzerActif.Count >= indexBuzzer Then
        Dim buzzer As Derby.ClsBuzzer
        buzzer = collBuzzerActif(indexBuzzer)
        If buzzer.boolOn And buzzer.intDuree > 0 Then
            ChangerStatutDataLogger(True)
            If collBuzzerActif.Count >= indexBuzzer + 1 Then
                TimerBuzzer.Interval = buzzer.intDuree
                TimerBuzzer.Enabled = True
            End If
        Else
            ChangerStatutDataLogger(False)
            If collBuzzerActif.Count >= indexBuzzer + 1 Then
                TimerBuzzer.Interval = buzzer.intDuree
                TimerBuzzer.Enabled = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: A service runs with System Admin by default, has no environment variables, and no credentials.  Best thing to do is to start service with a user account.Open the Windows Services console (Start Menu > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services). ...
Click on the Log On tab. ...
Click on the This account radio button. ...
After clicking on the Browse button, the Select User or Service Account dialog will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Timer you could use a Task and some ManualResetEvent.  When your service starts execute this ONCE,

```
_TimerBuzzerTask = Task.Run(Sub() TimerBuzzer_Tick())
```

And then make these changes

```
Private Sub RefreshMQTTScreen(....)
    indexBuzzer = 1
    TimerBuzzerInterval = buzzer.intDuree
    _TimerBuzzer_Enabled.Set()
End Sub

Private _TimerBuzzerTask As Task
Private _TimerBuzzer_Enabled As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)
Private _TimerBuzzer As New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False) '_TimerBuzzer.Set to end task
Private TimerBuzzerInterval As Integer = 1000

Private Sub TimerBuzzer_Tick()
    Do
        _TimerBuzzer_Enabled.WaitOne() 'to enable  _TimerBuzzer_Enabled.Set()
        _TimerBuzzer_Enabled.Reset()
        If collBuzzerActif.Count >= indexBuzzer Then
            Dim buzzer As Derby.ClsBuzzer
            buzzer = collBuzzerActif(indexBuzzer)

            If buzzer.boolOn AndAlso buzzer.intDuree > 0 Then
                ChangerStatutDataLogger(True)
                If collBuzzerActif.Count >= indexBuzzer + 1 Then
                    TimerBuzzerInterval = buzzer.intDuree
                    _TimerBuzzer_Enabled.Set()
                End If
            Else
                ChangerStatutDataLogger(False)
                If collBuzzerActif.Count >= indexBuzzer + 1 Then
                    TimerBuzzerInterval = buzzer.intDuree
                    _TimerBuzzer_Enabled.Set()
                End If
            End If

        End If
    Loop While _TimerBuzzer.WaitOne(TimerBuzzerInterval) 'ticks every second
End Sub
```

If your service stops execute this,

```
 _TimerBuzzer.Set
```

For obvious reasons I couldn't test this.